# White flash after splash screen and before app loads in React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am encountering an issue on React-Native android, after installing the app and opened, app launches the splash screen and within 2 seconds a white flash appears and reloads the splash screen again.

Appreciate any suggestion to mitigate this issue.

I am using React-Native v0.36.

Comment: You might be encountering some blank view before your splash screen.

Comment: @Codesingh, what is some blackview? I'm seeing the flash after loading splash screen.

Comment: i mean is there any <View> in the path until control reaches splash screen?

Comment: @Codesingh, it took a while for me to make sure there are NO empty View before it reaches splash screen.

Comment: please share the code

Comment: Various potential solutions in this rn issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1402